# "Comunidade" respondendo em inglês

Tags: suporte

O robô esta respondendo porém em inglês.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/524844/existe-algum-elemento-em-php-que-mostre-a-vari%c3%a1vel-apenas-se-ela-exista)